# Forcing template member function to instantiate

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, instantiation

I have a class C in the namespace N with a public template member function F as follows:

```
namespace N {
    class C {
    public:
        template<int I>
        void F() {
            // ...
        }
    };
};
```

The values of `I` for `N::C::F<I>` are not known until runtime. However, the value of `I` is constrained such that `0 <= I < 2^8`. I am looking for a way to force this function to expand the template to all 256 possible forms.

So far, I have manually created a static array within a second function of `C` that points to every possible function:

```
        template<int I>
        void F() {
            // ...
        }

        void G(int I) {
            static void(* const funcs[256])() = {
                F<0>, F<1>, F<2>, ...
            };

            funcs[I]();
        }
```

though I am left wondering if there is a better way. I already have a macro in `N` that is responsible for constructing a separate struct for each value of `I` (for use by F itself) and was looking if I could possibly integrate the instantiation of the template member function somehow in it:

```
    template<int> struct S;

    #define M(I, n) \
        template<> struct S<I> { \
            static const char name[] = #n; \
            /*
                Some how instantiate the function here, like (just guessing here):

                static const SEvaluator<I> eval = &C::F<I>;

                given

                template<int I>
                using SEvaluator = void(*)();
            */
        };

    M(0, "foo"); M(1, "bar");

    #undef M
```

My proposed method does not work as is and the compiler complains about F not being a constexpr. F manipulates several variables of `C` and calls external methods and could not be declared constexpr. Is there a way to salvage this or do I have to resort to my first hackish method?

Comment: Kind of darting around your question, but can't `I` just be an ordinary function parameter? I don't see much benefit you can potentially get here by generating 256 versions of a function and paying for the cost of indirect branching (unavoidable when the actual value is determined at runtime) just to allow some optimizations based on `I` being known compile time. It seems to be trading a much smaller overhead for a much bigger one. Like what about hand-unrolling loops inside `F`? That kind of stuff should be much more straightforward and give much more gain in return.

Comment: @Ike For context, `F` carries out the logic of various opcodes `I`. The virtual machine will loop across a ROM and call `F` on the current byte. F consists of a bunch of if statements checking if the given `I` has a given addressing mode, functionality, etc. Currently I have these if statements all evaluated procedurally for every opcode, but I had figured that dividing the logic up into individual branch-less functions and creating a jump table would introduce performance gains. (1/2)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the binary overhead of having more functions and the evaluation  overhead of an extra indirect branch will outweight the overhead of evaluating a bunch of unneccessary if-statements in terms of performance. I can't say I have much knowledge on lower-level optimization so this approach at least made sense in my head, but how would you suggest I improve otherwise? (2/2

Comment: I see -- if you're effectively simulating a jump table and the code generated for `F` is relatively small and/or very branchy in nature (lots of `if/else` inside), it may be quite worthwhile to seek this. Where I was a bit worried was just the size of this jump table and the potential amount of code generated along with the potential loss of inlining capabilities (if `F` is small) or icache issues (if `F` is large) -- we might lose more than we gain there. I'd be curious as to how it fares -- it's a very interesting example of more code and one broad branch vs. less code with smaller branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `index_sequence<I...>` (C++14) and expand `I` into the static array.

```c++
template<std::size_t... Is>
void G(int i, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using C = void(C::*)();
    static C funcs[sizeof...(Is)] = { &C::F<Is>... };
    (this->*funcs[i])();
}

void G(int i) {
    G(i, std::make_index_sequence<256>());
}
```

For a non-C++14 solution you can write your own version of an `index_sequence`:

```c++
template<int... Is>
struct index_sequence { };

template<int N, int... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

template<int... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> { };
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I've been bested by Batman. I'll post this anyway : the principle is the same, it's just done another way around.

```
template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto const &makeFunctions(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    static auto funcs = {&N::C::F<Idx>...};
    return funcs;
}

auto const &function(std::size_t i) { return *(begin(makeFunctions(std::make_index_sequence<256>{})) + i); }
```

Call :

```
N::C c;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    (c.*function(i))();
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c883c80b6324a980)